# LINQ query stores values in KeyValuePair<string, string> list but then cannot store them all with addrange

Tags: c#, linq, select, parameters, nested

The following LINQ query gets all parameters for all stations , every station (x.station) has X parameters (x.parameters) and I need all of them for both 'Result' and 'Values'. It might be a bit confusing at first since this line:

```
 from x in selection.Parameters
```

represents x stations, not x parameters.

LINQ query:

```
        var selectionData = 
            from x in selection.Parameters
            select new
            {
                Result = "(p.col_IdEstacion = " + x.Station + " and p.col_Sigla in(" +
                            ("'" + string.Join("','", x.Parameters) + "'") + "))",
                Values = 
                (
                    from y in x.Parameters
                    select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
                        x.Station.ToString(), y)).ToList()
            };
```

the reason why I'm doing this is because i want to store all parameters in all stations stored in 'Values' later on in a KeyValuePair List:

```
  List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>  myList
```

**UPDATED**: found out the code is working , what im doing wrong is to add 'Values' to the list, it might be the FirstOrDefault() that takes only the first one:

```
      values.AddRange(selectionData.Select(d => d.Values).FirstOrDefault());
```

**ANSWER**: found out the correct way to store all values retrieved with LINQ is using  **SelectMany** like this:

valores.AddRange(selectionData.SelectMany(d => d.Values))

Thanks

Comment: Tried to improve readability and simplified. Hope I didn't mess it up.

Comment: Add your entity class

Comment: Range variables in linq expressions work kind of like an iterator in a foreach loop. You cant access each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER**: found out the correct way to store all values retrieved with LINQ is using  **SelectMany** like this:

valores.AddRange(selectionData.SelectMany(d => d.Values))

Answer (score 1):

You could try it with
`ToDictionary` instead

But as i dont speak this kind of linq, i only work with the method chaining, i'm not sure if this will compile, but maybe it is a hint for you what to try.

```
var selectionData = 
            from x in selection.Parameters
            select new
            {
                Result = "(p.col_IdEstacion = " + x.Station + " and p.col_Sigla in(" +
                            ("'" + string.Join("','", x.Parameters) + "'") + "))",
                Values = x.Parameters.ToDictionary(k=>k.Station.ToString(), v=>v)
            };
```

Comment: Thanks , adding values to a dictionary could work  but forgot to mention that i wanted to store them in a List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>  later on. Still could use the dictionary to store them in the list manually later on. I was trying to do it all with LINQ

Comment: found out the LINQ works, i was adding the values like :  values.AddRange(selectionData.Select(d => d.Values).FirstOrDefault());